# How to add a row dynamically when using server-side processing?

Tags: jquery, server-side, datatables

I am using datatables with server-side processing turned on.

There are instances where persistence in database is done asynchronously, but I do get the event on server when something will be added and need to show that on the client. In that case, I want to add a row on client and increment the count.

The way I implemented is by following these steps:

1. set bserverside to false
2. call `fnAddData()`
3. set bserverside to true

This way row gets added on the client but since client only had current page - the total number of records become (page size + 1) instead of (previous total count + 1). I tried changing `settings._iRecordsTotal` but it doesnt help.

Can you please help or provide me with any other approach?

Answer (score 1):

There is a third party plugin for adding new records into the JQuery DataTable http://jquery-datatables-editable.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/index.html.

You can see example in the http://jquery-datatables-editable.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/addingrecords.html and documentation on the http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-editable/wiki/AddingNewRecords